# Unable to toggle button click event on AJAX request

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
<div class=" pull-right">
    <?php if ($placement['placementStatus'] == Campaign::STATUS_IN_PROGRESS): ?>
    <a class="pausebtn btn btn-small" onclick="pausePlacement($(this), '<?=$placement['placementTag']?>');" href="#"><i class="elusive-pause"></i></a>
    <?php else: ?>
    <a class="startbtn btn btn-small" onclick="startPlacement($(this), '<?=$placement['placementTag']?>');" href="#" ><i class="elusive-play"></i></a>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <a class="trashbtn btn btn-small" onclick="deletePlacement($(this), '<?=$placement['adId']?>');" href="#"><i class="elusive-trash"></i></a>
</div>

function pausePlacement(el, placementTag) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/campaign/pausePlacement/' + campaignId + '/' + placementTag,
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(data) {
            if(data.responsecode != '1') {
                bootbox.alert(data.validationerror);
            } else {
                el.html('<i class="elusive-play">');
                el.off('click').on('click', function() {
                    startPlacement(el, placementTag);
                });
            }
        }
    });     
}

function startPlacement(el, placementTag) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/campaign/startPlacement/' + campaignId + '/' + placementTag,
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(data) {
            if(data.responsecode != '1') {
                bootbox.alert(data.validationerror);
            } else {
                el.html('<i class="elusive-pause">');
                el.off('click').on('click', function() {
                    pausePlacement(el, placementTag);
                });
            }
        }
    });     
}
```

If the initial state is paused for instance, then the play button is displayed. If you hit the play button, it changes the state to playing and now it becomes the pause button. But now if you hit the pause button, for some maddening reason it makes another ajax request to change the state to playing and then makes a subsequent request to pause the placement.

So the first click, only 1 ajax request. The second click, 2 ajax requests. On the third click, 1 again. And so forth.

Why is it doing this and what do I need to change? Thanks

Comment: Can you show how you call the functions?

Comment: Added the PHP/HTML to the top

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/off/):

> *The `off()` method removes event handlers that were attached with `.on()`.*

But you have handlers set via inline `onclick="...` attributes. So after the first click you have both an inline `onclick="...` *and* a jQuery-bound click handler. Bind the click handlers with jQuery in the first place.

```
<?php if ($placement['placementStatus'] == Campaign::STATUS_IN_PROGRESS): ?>
<a class="pausebtn btn btn-small" data-placement="<?=$placement['placementTag']?>"
   href="#"><i class="elusive-pause"></i></a>
<?php else: ?>
<a class="startbtn btn btn-small" data-placement="<?=$placement['placementTag']?>"
   href="#" ><i class="elusive-play"></i></a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

And then:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a.pausebtn").click(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        pausePlacement($this, $this.attr("data-placement"));
    });
    $("a.startbtn").click(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        startPlacement($this, $this.attr("data-placement"));
    });
});
```

Or, given that your existing functions are *almost* identical, you can probably combine them to something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a.pausebtn,a.startbtn").click(function() {
       var $this = $(this),
           placementTag = $this.attr("data-placement");

       $.ajax({
          url: '/campaign/'
               + ($this.hasClass("pausebtn") ? 'pausePlacement' : 'startPlacement')
               + '/' + campaignId + '/' + placementTag,
          dataType: 'json',
          type: 'GET',
          success: function(data) {
             if(data.responsecode != '1') {
                bootbox.alert(data.validationerror);
             } else {
                $this.toggleClass('btnpause btnstart')
                     .find('i').toggleClass('elusive-pause elusive-start');
             }
          }
       });
    });
});
```

That is, bind a click handler to whichever of `pausebtn` and `startbtn` exists initially. Then within that handler set the URL for the Ajax call according to which class the clicked item has, then on `success` toggle the classes.